# Сохранение, редактирование, удаление содержимого JSON файла

Tags: c#, .net, json, файлы

**Добрый день!**

Подскажите простые действия с библиотекой json.net 
Удаление, редактирование, запись с файлом JSON. 
**Спасибо!**

Comment: Иначе говоря: научите меня работать с json.net! Есть же [документация](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под удалением и редактированием? JSON.NET занимается десериализацией из (например) файла в объектную структуру. Как редактировать ваши объекты, JSON.NET не знает и знать не хочет.

Comment: Интересует перезапись значения в json файле.

Comment: При помощи JSON.NET - никак. Обновляйте значение в объекте и сериализуйте его заново. Сериализованный объект (в том числе JSON) - это строка, он предназначен для передачи (реже - хранения) данных, никак не для их редактирования